# Offline Mobile generate 6 digit code for 2factor authentication

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, algorithm

I am trying to generate 6 unique digit from ***OFFLINE*** mobile app containing user information such as `id` and use this code to verify 2factor authentication.

So mobile take contain `user_id = 5` and I add `unix timestamp = 1571936674` and concatenate them for example it will be `1571936674-5`.

Then I am going to do the same algorithm process on Web App to generate the same token using `unix timestamp` and `user_id` and neglect the time difference between both timestamps.

## Problem is:

How I am going to reduce those large digits to only 6 digits?! on both the OFFLINE mobile and server so that they could match?

Comment: Why not use the standard [TOTP Algorithm](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238)?. There are several libraries available for PHP and others to do this for you.

Comment: @MER yes but remember that Mobile is offline and not connected with PC or server

Comment: Per MER's comment, maybe https://github.com/jiangts/JS-OTP will solve your problem...

Comment: @Ahmed, yes, this algorithm is based on the current time. No need to be online. This is what the Google Authenticator app uses and that works whether or not you are online.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is necessary for you to generate a fixed length output where length = 6. You can make use hash functions which return a fixed length outputs. For eg: SHA 256

Comment: Yes but this will generate code on mobile that matches PC while both are not connected and mobile is offline?